# how to convert mid to mp3 using ffmpeg

Tags: python-3.x

I have mid.mid file and want to convert in mp3 format but it shows: mid1.mid: Invalid data found when processing input

here is cmd i'm using :

ffmpeg -i "mid1.mid" "out.mp3"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 from pydub import AudioSegment
 sound = AudioSegment.from_file("/path/to/file.mid", format="mid")
 sound.export("/output/path/file.mp3", format="mp3")
```